# Interactive 2D (t-SNE) Scatterplot visualization

Tags: networking, visualization, scatter-plot

I´m searching for a tool, that allows me to browse a Scatterplot created with t-SNE. scatterD3 seems to be the best I could find so far, but I don´t know if it can do all the things I want.

Every dot has an unique label and I have classification informations for the labels. I want to be able to:

- click on/choose a class to color all labels in that class
- choose multiple class and the dots get colored in multiple colors
- click on a dot and get all the classes
- select multiple dots and get a matrix with the classes
- zoom and move around in the plot
- search for labels

Do you know such a tool? Or is there a way to program something like that using python or R?

Comment: `scatterD3` author here. You should be able to do much of what you want with scatterD3 + Shiny, but it won't really be "out of the box". It also depends on the number of dots you have, as `scatterD3` starts becoming slow when you reach several thousands of points.

Answer (score 0):

VisuMap 5.0 can do pretty much all you listed services for 2D and 3D t-SNE maps. VisuMap is however a commercial software product for Windows platform.